# Cannot Enable ADB for Kindle Fire HD

Tags: adb, kindle-fire

I'm trying to root an 8th generation Kindle HD Fire (Fire OS 6.3.0.1)
I've turned on the `Developer options`, however, `Enable ADB` isn't listed under it. Is there another place I should look for the ADB setting?

I've done the following:

```
Settings > Security & Privacy >Turned on Apps from Unknown
Settings > Device Options > About Fire Tablet > Tapped Serial 7 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on "USB Debugging". That's what it's called in Developer Options.